# Laravel blade и Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, blade

Хочу связать ответ laravel сервера и Vue (Props) динамически, но ничего не получается...
Пример:

Есть `session('response.error)'` (в ней `true || false`) и хочу передать динамически во Vue

```
<example :error="{{ session('response.error) }}"></example>
```

Будет ошибка, но если передать статически то всё работает, но  Vue возвращает строку, что мне не нужно!

```
<example error="{{ session('response.error) }}"></example>
```

В этом случае: если будет `true`, во Vue придёт `1`, а если `false`, во Vue придёт пустая строка. Такое поведение очень сильно будоражит

Comment: попробуйте поставить для error type Boolean

Comment: Это не работает, vue сразу выдаёт ошибку, так как возвращается string если передавать статически

Comment: у Вас оно точно возвращает значение как true? Что за ошибка в `<example :error` варианте ?

Comment: Error compiling template, возвращает true || false если это есть в сессии после определённых действий

Comment: У меня вроде все как нодо: https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/YJyEJQ

Comment: Ну так вы же не в blade пытаетесь вставить php во Vue

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83932/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: вы решили проблему? Очень интересно.